# ng-repeat is not showing data but shows correct length

Tags: angularjs

I have a strange problem with showing some data using ng-repeat.

If my markup code is this:

```
  <p ng-repeat="d in data"> {{d}} </p>
```

nothing shows up however if i do

```
 <p> {{data}} </p>
```

the following is shown:

[203507,"Giannis","Antetokounmpo","Giannis Antetokounmpo","Antetokounmpo, Giannis","G. Antetokounmpo","1994-12-06T00:00:00","Greece","Greece","Greece","6-11","222",3,"34","Forward","Active",1610612749,"Bucks","MIL","bucks","Milwaukee","giannis_antetokounmpo",2013,2016,"N","Y"]

I checked the length of the array using {{data.length}} and it says 26 which is accurate. someone please explain?

my code to get data in scope is a json object:

```
   $scope.data = info.resultSets[0].rowSet[0];
```

Comment: May be its not parsed JSON object try `JSON.parse`

Comment: Your code is working. http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/6841/

Comment: Is your data a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have duplicate values in the array you need to add 'track by $index'

```
<p ng-repeat="d in data track by $index"> {{d}} </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're facing this issue because your array contains duplicates, you can check further information [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes)